# Using DATEDIF to convert days to month not working

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I can calculate the days between two dates by doing =[Due Date]-[Start Date] and that works. But I want to calculate how many months are between the two dates. I found this formula =DATEDIF([Start Date], [Due Date],"ym") but it does not work, Sharepoint just says: Syntax error.

Can anyone please assist?

Thank you!

Please note I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the language the SharePoint is configured in, it is possible that you need to use `;` instead of `,`. So try to use `=DATEDIF([Start Date]; [Due Date]; "ym")`

Hint: Most formlars can be tested in excel beforehand...

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated, this worked.